# Group a Scala list by custom logic

Tags: scala, list

I have a custom logic to group a list of names by their first letter and I can achieve it by the following:

```
val names = List("Adam", "Barbara", "Bob", "Charlie", "Damien", "Elaine", "Florence", "Gwen")
names.map{
  case x if x.startsWith("A") => (1, x)
  case x if x.startsWith("B") => (1, x)
  case x if x.startsWith("C") => (2, x)
  case x if x.startsWith("D") => (2, x)
  case x if x.startsWith("E") => (3, x)
  case x if x.startsWith("F") => (3, x)
  case default => (0, default)
}.groupBy(_._1)
```

The logic may change. For example, next time I may want to group all names starting with A, F and G to group 1 or I may add all letters up to Z. A more advanced logic would be to take the first two letters and group names starting with Ad and Ba to group 1, in which case Adam and Barbara would be in the same group.

I'd like to know if there is a more idiomatic approach, where I can write `startsWith` lesser number of times.

From [Tanjin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43414258/group-a-scala-list-by-custom-logic/43414630#43414630), I further refactored `groups` to:

```
val groups = List(
      (List("A", "B"),1),
      (List("C", "D"),2),
      (List("E", "F"),3)
    ).flatMap{ case (l,i) => l.map((_, i)) }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try this - all you would need to do is alter your `groups`:

```
def categorize(groups: Seq[(String, Int)]) = (s: String) => {
  groups.find(category => category._1 == s.head.toString)
    .map(c => (c._2, s)).getOrElse((0, s))
}
val groups = Seq(("A", 1), ("B", 1), ("C", 2), ("D", 2), ("E", 3), ("F", 3))

names.map(categorize(groups)).groupBy(_._1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with only `groupBy`

```
def groupBy[K](f: String => K): scala.collection.immutable.Map[K,List[String]]
```

Notice `groupBy` takes function as argument

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> def f(x: String) = x match {
     | case x if x.startsWith("A") => (1, x)
     |   case x if x.startsWith("B") => (1, x)
     |   case x if x.startsWith("C") => (2, x)
     |   case x if x.startsWith("D") => (2, x)
     |   case x if x.startsWith("E") => (3, x)
     |   case x if x.startsWith("F") => (3, x)
     |   case default => (0, default)
     | }
f: (x: String)(Int, String)

scala> val names = List("Adam", "Barbara", "Bob", "Charlie", "Damien", "Elaine", "Florence", "Gwen")
names: List[String] = List(Adam, Barbara, Bob, Charlie, Damien, Elaine, Florence, Gwen)

scala> names.groupBy(f(_)._1)
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,List[String]] = Map(2 -> List(Charlie, Damien), 1 -> List(Adam, Barbara, Bob), 3 -> List(Elaine, Florence), 0 -> List(Gwen))
```

Comment: Thanks @pamu! But I was looking for maybe a way where I can mention startsWith lesser number of times.

Answer (score 1):

#### Code

```
    def categorize[A](names: List[String], prefixGroups: Seq[(A,Set[String])]): Map[Option[A],List[String]] = 
    names.groupBy(name => prefixGroups.find{case (group, prefixes) => prefixes.exists(name.startsWith)}.map(_._1))

    val result = categorize(List("Anna","Bob","Carla","Debbie","Eddie"), Seq(1 -> Set("A","B"), 2 -> Set("C","D")))

    println("all: " + result)
    println("only valid: " + result.filterKeys(_.isDefined).map{case (Some(k),v) => k -> v})
```

#### Output

```
all: Map(Some(1) -> List(Anna, Bob), None -> List(Eddie), Some(2) -> List(Carla, Debbie))
only valid: Map(1 -> List(Anna, Bob), 2 -> List(Carla, Debbie))
```

#### Changes wrt Tanjin's solution

- The groups are given in a more concise format `Seq[(Key,Set[String])]`, aggregating prefixes of the same group.
- The result retains unmatched names.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late to the party but I wanted to share another nice solution if you're willing to store your groups slightly different. Note that this version will only work if you're checking for the first letter but you can easily update it to work in other cases as well.

*"Behold the power of Maps"*

First, we'll store our groups as a map of `Int` to a sequence of characters which will be our prefixes. I'm using the multi-line syntax for clarity:

```scala
val groups = Map(
  1 -> Seq('A', 'B'),
  2 -> Seq('C', 'D'),
  3 -> Seq('E', 'F')
)
```

Now we build an [inverted index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index) from our dictionary. This means we kind of swap the keys with the values in our map. It's not exactly swapping because we need to map each sequence of prefixes into multiple tuples:

```scala
val inverted = groups
  .flatMap { case (id, prefixes) => prefixes.map(_ -> id) } // Swap keys w/ values
  .withDefault(_ => 0)                                      // Set the default
```

Finally, the `groupBy` call is quite neat and tidy:

```scala
names.groupBy(name => inverted(name(0)))
```

---

In the end I would add the fact that operations on `Map`s are generally faster. But anyway if you don't have a really huge list of names you should be fine either way. The other nice thing about this approach is that you can reuse the first two maps: `groups` and `inverted`. So the only thing that it's recomputed over and over again is the last `groupBy` call - if you're checking multiple lists of names.

I hope this is helpful, enjoy!